# Delete emails from specific source in mailx/BSD mail

Tags: email, bsd, mailx

I need to delete all emails from a specific source. I can list all of the emails with the `f source@emailaddress.com` but I'm having to dump it to something like awk and back into mail... or copy all of the email header numbers individually.

Is there a faster way or a way integrated into the program that will do it automatically?

Comment: Are you specifically using bsd-mailx? IIRC, s-nail (heirloom-mailx) has much more extensive filtering.

Comment: Yes, I am specifically using the BSD mail program.  It's the default on SDF that I've always used; I just let my inbox get away from me.

Comment: See my proposed solution below.  If some/all of my assumptions are wrong, please indicate corrections and I may be able to propose an alternate strategy.

Answer (score 0):

The `procmail` package includes a handy tool called `formail` which allows the user to iterate over individual messages of a traditional mbox-style mailbox.  My approach to tasks like this has been to split the mbox into individual messages, use standard UNIX tools (grep, rm) to process the messages, and then re-assemble the mailbox.  Naturally, this needs to be done with the `sendmail` process stopped, so that no new mail arrives while you're working.  Only a brief downtime is necessary.

You don't say which BSD you're on, but I'll assume FreeBSD.  I will also assume that you're using `bash` for your shell, and that you have root access to the box, or at least sufficient sudo privileges to start/stop the `sendmail` instance on your machine, and to write directly to your mailbox `/var/mail/$USER`.

Install the `procmail` package and read the `formail` man page.

```
$ sudo pkg install procmail
$ man formail
```

Make a clean workspace:

```
$ mkdir ~/work
$ cd ~/work
```

Create a simple script and make it executable:

```
$ cat << EOF > cat-msg.sh
#!/bin/sh

cat > msg-$FILENO.txt
EOF
$ chmod 755 cat-msg.sh
```

And another:

```
$ cat << EOF > split-mbox.sh 
#!/bin/sh

export FILENO="00000"
formail -s cat-msg.sh < "$@"
EOF
$ chmod 755 split-mbox.sh
```

Stop the mailserver:

```
$ sudo service sendmail stop
```

Split your mbox into multiple files in the current directory:

```
./split-mbox.sh /var/mail/$USER
```

That command reads your mailbox, and creates files `msg-#####.txt` in the current directory.  It does not write to or delete your `/var/mail/$USER` mailbox, so no harm done.

Using `grep`, identify the `msg-*.txt` files you want to delete, and examine a few of them to ensure that you are certain your regexp correctly targets only the messages you want to delete.  It is okay to use multiple regexp passes, but you must be sure that each regexp does not have any false positives.

```
$ grep -lF '^From: spammer@example.com' msg*.txt
$ (use less to spot-check a few or all of them)
```

If the message files identified by `grep` are indeed messages you want to delete, then:

```
$ grep -lF '^From: spammer@example.com' msg*.txt | xargs rm -v
```

If there are multiple regexps you want to use to find the messages to delete, you can go back and `grep` again with a different regexp and spot-check those hits, etc.

Once you've successfully deleted all the offending messages, backup your mailbox, write the remaining `msg*.txt` files to your mailbox, and re-start the mailserver:

```
$ cp -vp /var/mail/$USER mbox-$USER
$ cat msg*.txt > /var/mail/$USER
$ sudo service sendmail start
```

If you find these tools handy, and wish to keep them for future use, then:

```
$ sudo mv -vi split-mbox.sh cat-msg.sh /usr/local/bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we're making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be; at least when it comes to OpenBSD 7.2 which is the version of OpenBSD I use and the system where I ran the following command in `mail(1)` to delete email from a specific address:

```
d source@emailaddress.com
```

Non-interactively:

```
echo "d source@emailaddress.com" | mail -f
```